# $pq-6$, $qr-6$ and $rp-6$ are all perfect squares. Prove that $p+q+r-9$ is also a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $p$, $q$ and $r$ are distinct prime numbers such that $pq-6$, $qr-6$ and $rp-6$
>   are all perfect squares. Prove that $p+q+r-9$ is also a perfect
>   square.

Now comes a part where I explain what I have tried and concluded so far. In short: nothing, except that only one prime number can be 2. In fact, finding a working example proved to be a challenge. And this is not homework, I'm too old for it.

**EDIT:** Actually, I turned out to be smarter than I thought. Suppose that we have three odd primes $p,q,r$. In that case at least two are equal to 1 or 3 (modulo 4). In both cases their product is equal to 1 (modulo 4). Subtract 6 and and you get 3 (modulo 4). And such number cannot be a perfect square.

So at least one prime number has to be $2$, say $p$. I solved 1/3 of the problem. Probably enough to avoid downvotes :)

Comment: Must be 2 or can be 2?

Comment: No more than one prime can be two. But that's a trivial conclusion.

Comment: Do the primes have to be distinct?

Comment: @TheShortOne Yes., thanks! I'll edit the post in a second.

Comment: One working example would be $(p,q,r)=(2,5,11)$.

Comment: Another two would be $(p,q,r)=(2,101,131)$, and $(p,q,r)=(2,971,1061)$.

Comment: Sorry, I was just writing my answer and didn't notice your edit that says the same thing. Now we just have to finish this.

Comment: Primes under to $10^4$ other than $3$, $5$, $11$, $53$, $101$, $131$, $971$, $1061$, $1571$, $2741$, $3203$, $3701$, $4421$, $5003$, $6053$, $7691$, $9803$ do not occur, and the three triplets in my earlier comments are the only solutions with $q,r\leq10^4$,

Comment: What are the four square-roots in each of the cases you have found ?

Comment: If p and r are 971 and 1061, the four square-roots are 44,45,46 and 1015.  If only there were some connection between these numbers...

Comment: The connection is that $2q-6,q+r-7,2r-6$ are always a triple of consecutive squares in the cases I've seen. I'm writing an answer about this now, but there are still some details to work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p=2$ be the even prime and without loss of generality assume $p<q<r$. Since $p,q,r$ are primes this means $r\geq 5$.

We shall first show the following:

> **Lemma.** Let $2=p<q<r$ be primes and
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> 2q-6 &= x^2\\
> 2r-6 &= y^2\\
> qr-6 &= z^2
> \end{align}
> $$
>   for some integers $x,y,z\geq 0$. Then
>   $$
> z+y = r
> $$

**Proof.** Taking equations $2$ and $3$, we form the following:
$$
\begin{align}
z^2 &\equiv -6 \equiv y^2 \pmod r\\
(z+y)(z-y) &\equiv 0 \pmod r
\end{align}
$$
Therefore $r$ divides $z+y$ or $z-y$. We first assume the latter, then
$$
\begin{align}
z-y &\equiv 0  \pmod r\\
z &= y + kr
\end{align}
$$
for some $k\geq 0$ since $z> y$. But now
$$
\begin{align}
0 &< y+kr=z =\sqrt{qr-6} < \sqrt{r^2} = r\\
0 & < y+kr < r \implies k=0
\end{align}
$$
This means that
$$
z = y
$$
which is not possible. Hence we must have instead
$$
\begin{align}
z+y &\equiv 0 \pmod r\\
z+y &= kr\\
0 < kr &= z+y\\
&= \sqrt{qr-6}+\sqrt{2r-6}\\
&< \sqrt{r^2} + \sqrt{4r}\\
&= r+2\sqrt{r}\\
&< 2r\\
0<kr &< 2r
\end{align}
$$
where the last equality is because
$$
r\geq 5 \implies 4r < r^2 \implies 2\sqrt{r} < r
$$
Therefore we must have precisely $k=1$, giving $z+y=r$.

$$
\tag*{$\square$}
$$

---

We now show that

> **Proposition.** Let $p=2$ and
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> 2r-6 &= y^2\\
> qr-6 &= z^2\\
> z+y &= r
> \end{align}
> $$
>   for some integers $q,r,y,z\geq 0$. Then
>   $$
> p+q+r-9 = (y-1)^2
> $$

**Proof.** Using $z+y=r$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
r &= z+y\\
&= \sqrt{qr-6} + \sqrt{2r-6}\\
\sqrt{qr-6} &= r - \sqrt{2r-6}\\
qr-6 &= r^2-2r\sqrt{2r-6} + (2r-6)\\
qr &= r^2-2r\sqrt{2r-6} + 2r\\
q &= r -2\sqrt{2r-6} + 2\\
p+q+r-9 = q+r-7 &= (2r-5) -2\sqrt{2r-6}\\
&= (y^2+1) - 2y\\
&= (y-1)^2
\end{align}
$$

$$
\tag*{$\square$}
$$

---

**Edit 1:** Deriving a formula similar to Will Jagy's.

> **Proposition.** Primes $q,r$ satisfies
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> q &= 2(6k\pm 1)^2+3 = 5 + 24u\\
> r &= 2(6k\pm 2)^2+3 = 11 + 24v
> \end{align}
> $$
>   for some integers $u,v\geq 0$ (must be same sign). This in turn gives
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> x &= \sqrt{2q-6} = 2(6k \pm 1)\\
> y &= \sqrt{2r-6} = 2(6k \pm 2)\\
> z &= \sqrt{qr-6} = 72k^2\pm 36k+7\\
> q+r-9 &= (3(4k\pm 1))^2
> \end{align}
> $$

**Proof.** We start from
$$
\begin{align}
2q-6&=x^2\implies -6\equiv x^2\pmod q\\
2r-6&=y^2\implies -6\equiv y^2\pmod r
\end{align}
$$
Since $-6$ is a square, by Quadratic Reciprocity we get $q,r\equiv 1,5,7,11\pmod{24}$.

Now the third equation gives
$$
qr-6 = z^2\implies qr=z^2+6
$$
Since $z^2+6\equiv 6,7,10,15,18,22\pmod{24}$, the only possible combinations of $(q,r)\pmod{24}$ are
$$
(1,7),(5,11),(7,1),(11,5)
$$
For $q\equiv 1,7 \pmod{24}$, we observe that
$$
2q-6 =x^2\implies 20,8\equiv x^2\pmod{24}
$$
which is not possible. Therefore up to interchanging $q$ and $r$, we may assume that
$$
(q,r)\equiv (5,11) \pmod{24}
$$
Hence we now have
$$
\begin{align}
q &= 2a^2+3 = 5+24u\\
r &= 2b^2+3 = 11+24v
\end{align}
$$
for some integers $a,b,u,v\geq 0$. By checking $\pmod{24}$, we can show that
$$
a = 6m\pm 1,\quad b = 6n\pm 2
$$
Further, using $q=r-2\sqrt{2r-6}+2$ as before:
$$
\begin{align}
q &= r-2\sqrt{2r-6}+2\\
72 m^2 \pm 24 m + 5 &= 72 n^2 \pm 24 n + 5\\
9 m^2 \pm 6 m + 1 &= 9 n^2 \pm 6 n + 1\\
(3m \pm 1)^2 &= (3n\pm 1)^2
\end{align}
$$
it must be the case that $m=n=k$ and $6m\pm 1,6n\pm 2$ has the same sign. Then a direct computation gives the formula for $z$ and $p+q+r-9$.

Comment: Well done! Does this solution necessarily bound the difference between $y$ and $x$? This was one avenue orion and I both attacked, and I'm curious about the resolution.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks! However I want to add that it's guided by your answer. My original attempt was stuck after I found $(q,r)\equiv (5,11)\pmod{24}$.  

For $x$ and $y$, using the relation near the end:
$$
q = r-2\sqrt{2r-6}+2
$$
we can derive
$$
x^2 = 2q-6 = (2r-2) - 4 \sqrt{2r-6} = (y^2+4)-4y = (y-2)^2
$$
Didn't put it in since it wasn't used.

Comment: Ah, excellent! I am heartened to have made the right guesses. Thanks for posting a full solution.

Comment: @YongHaoNg Just wonderful, from start to finish. I am also happy to see that so many people have found this problem to be interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @Oldboy Thanks for the problem! May I ask where is it from?

Comment: @YongHaoNg My son goes to a special high school for gifted and talented students of mathematics and physics. Students from that school won 100+ medals in IMOs so far, probably because they are dealing with problems like this one :) The problem came to me from my son who likes to "torture" me with difficult problems picked from the school. The exact origin of the problem is unknown ("I saw it somewhere", he said).

Answer (score 4):

By the work you've carried out in the edit, we may assume without loss of generality that $p=2$ and $p<q<r$. This transforms our statements to the following: given primes $q<r$ and  that $2q-6,2r-6,qr-6$ are squares, show that $q+r-7$ is also a square.

Conjecture: if $2q-6=s^2$ and $2r-6=t^2$, then $t=s+2$ and $q+r-7=(s+1)^2$. Further, $\sqrt{qr-6} = \frac{q+r}{2}-1$. This seems to match with the results of Will Jagy in another answer in the thread. Unfortunately, proving this has eluded me for a while and now I must go do other things. I'll come back to this.

Comment: Excellent. It appears that $2q-6=s^2$ and $2r-6=(s+2)^2$ is a *sufficient* condition, as it already implies that $qr-6$ is a perfect square, once you set $s=2n$ and realize that $qr-6=(3+2n+2n^2)^2$. So it only remains to show that $t=s+2$ is a *necessary* condition for the third perfect square. I'm investigating along the way that $2(r-q)=(t-s)(t+s)$ and trying to put a limit on $t-s$ factor.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer but a start:

A perfect square must equal $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. Thus, $6+n^2$ must be $2$ or $3$ modulo $4$. These remainders after division by $4$ can be built in the following ways:

$$1\times 2\equiv 2$$
$$2\times 3\equiv 2$$
$$1\times 3\equiv 3$$

In other words, remainders of both factors must not be the same! The only option is thus, that $p,q,r$ must have remainders modulo $4$ equal to $1$, $2$ and $3$ (must be different). That in turn means, that one of them must be $q=2$. It follows that $p+q+r-9\equiv 1 \mod 4$ - a perfect square of an odd number.

Now that we know a bit more about what $p,q,r$ must be, it might be easier to proceed. Especially the fact that one of them is $2$, should help simplify matters.

The original statement is now:

$$p=3+2n^2$$
$$r=3+2l^2$$
$$pr=6+m^2$$
and
$$p+r-7=x^2$$
where $p$ and $r$ are odd primes, $p=1\mod 4$, $r=3\mod 4$, and $x$ is an odd number. $n$ and $m$ must be odd and $l$ must be even, and $p+r$ turns out to be divisible by $8$.

At the end, I suspect we will need the fact that $p$ and $r$ are primes - just modular arithmetics won't be enough. Unique factorization will play a role.

---

Now observe the same equations modulo $3$. Perfect squares can only be equal to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$. The $0$ case is only if they are divisible by $3$. It can easily be shown that $n$ and $l$ are not divisible by $3$ except for the trivial solution $(p,q,r)=(3,2,5)$. Thus we have

$$p,r\equiv 2 \mod 3$$
$$p-r=2(n-l)(n+l)\equiv 0\mod 6$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an infinite family, where the two numbers $p,q$ are  not necessarily prime

$$  p  = 2(3k+2)^2 +3 $$
$$  q  = 2(3k+1)^2 +3 $$
I thought they were coprime, but not always. $\gcd(p,q) | 14,$ and both are odd, so the possible common factor is $7.$ Then, if $k \equiv 3 \pmod 7,$ both $p,q$ are multiples of $7.$ All the other rules in the question apply, though.  $$  \left(  18 x^{2}  + 24 x  + 11 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  + 1 }{ 14 }  \right)  -  \left(  18 x^{2}  + 12 x  + 5 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  + 5 }{ 14 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

```
3  p : 245 =  5 7^2    q : 203 =  7 29
10  p : 2051 =  7 293    q : 1925 =  5^2 7 11
17  p : 5621 =  7 11 73    q : 5411 =  7 773
24  p : 10955 =  5 7 313    q : 10661 =  7 1523
```

$$ $$

$$ p = 18 k^2 + 24 k + 11 $$
$$ q = 18 k^2 + 12 k + 5 $$
$$ 2p-6 = (6k+4)^2 $$
$$ 2q-6 = (6k+2)^2 $$
$$ pq - 6 =  (18k^2 + 18k + 7)^2  $$
$$ p+q-7 = ( 6k+3)^2  $$
$$ $$

Both prime, first few:

```
0  p : 11    q : 5
2  p : 131    q : 101
7  p : 1061    q : 971
27  p : 13781    q : 13451
42  p : 32771    q : 32261
67  p : 82421    q : 81611
137  p : 341141    q : 339491
172  p : 536651    q : 534581
287  p : 1489541    q : 1486091
317  p : 1816421    q : 1812611
447  p : 3607301    q : 3601931
487  p : 4280741    q : 4274891
497  p : 4458101    q : 4452131
552  p : 5497931    q : 5491301
597  p : 6429701    q : 6422531
632  p : 7204811    q : 7197221
662  p : 7904291    q : 7896341
772  p : 10746251    q : 10736981
1017  p : 18641621    q : 18629411
1292  p : 30077771    q : 30062261
1437  p : 37203941    q : 37186691
1497  p : 40374101    q : 40356131
1537  p : 42559541    q : 42541091
1652  p : 49163531    q : 49143701
1822  p : 59798051    q : 59776181
1827  p : 60126581    q : 60104651
1952  p : 68632331    q : 68608901
2027  p : 74005781    q : 73981451
2307  p : 95855861    q : 95828171
2377  p : 101759381    q : 101730851
2417  p : 105212021    q : 105183011
2517  p : 114095621    q : 114065411
```